# Raw MySQL with SQLAlchemy using Pyramid framework

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have recently made a decision to start using the Pyramid (python web framework) for my projects from now on.

I have also decided to use SQLalchemy, and I want to use raw MySQL (personal reasons) but still keep the ORM features.

The first part of the code in models.py reads:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()
```

Now from here how do I exectue a query for CREATE TABLE using raw MySQL.

the traditional SQLalchemy way would be:

```
class Page(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'pages'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(Text, unique=True)
  data = Column(Text)

def __init__(self, name, data):
    self.name = name
    self.data = data
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DBSession.execute('CREATE TABLE ....')
```

Have a look at `sqlalchemy.text()` for parametrized queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marco. I have tried the following:

`DBSession.execute( """
   CREATE TABLE .....
"""
)`

and recieve the following error: UnboundExecutionError: Could not
locate a bind configured on SQL expression or this Session

Comment: yes, you have to call DBSession.configure(bind=get_engine(...)) or something like that, but I'm not into pyramid yet and don't know how it is set up. I usually create the schema in pure sql then call reflect() on the connection...

Answer (score 3):

My own biased suggestion would be to use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/khufu_sqlalchemy to setup the sqlalchemy engine.

Then inside a pyramid view you can do something like:

```
from khufu_sqlalchemy import dbsession
db = dbsession(request)
db.execute("select * from table where id=:id", {'id':7})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `views.py` if you are adding form elements, first create an object of the database.

In your snippet, do it as

```
pg = Page()
```

and add it with

```
DBSession.add(pg)
```

for all the form elements you want to add e.g name and data from your snippet.

the final code would be similar to:

```
    pg = Page()
    name = request.params['name']
    data = request.params['data']
    DBSession.add(pg)
```